# Customize junitxml Pytest report to add multiple attributes from custom marker

Tags: python, xml, junit, pytest

Each test case in my test suite has multiple attributes associated with it that I wish to include in XML(`junit-xml`) report. 
Following code snippet gives a clear picture about it.

```
@data(*get_csv_data("csv/blah.csv"))
@unpack
@pytest.mark.run(order=70)
@pytest.mark.webtest.with_args(jira="QA5555", second="second_arg_add")
def test_your_stuff(self,arg1, arg2):
    # Actual Test
```

While customizing reports, it is easy to add attributes in `pytest-html` plugin, by adding parameters in `extras` attribute of `pytest-html`, as shown below.

In `conftest.py`

```
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
  pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
  outcome = yield
  report = outcome.get_result()
  extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
  if report.when == 'call':
     extra.append(pytest_html.extras.text("<blah>")
     report.extra = extra
```

Also, I can easily get the attributes

```
item.keywords.get('webtest').kwargs
```

How can I do the same for `junitxml`?

A few findings -

1. `junitxml` does not have `extras`
2. `record_xml_property` I do not want to use it as it is a feature in test. Also adding multiple arguments with decorator looks like a nice approach. I do not want to hamper code readability.

   ```
   def test_function(record_xml_property):
       record_xml_property("key", "value")
       assert 0
   ```
3. The following approach

   ```
   if hasattr(request.config, "_xml"):
   request.config._xml.add_custom_property(name, value)
   ```

   I was not able to get hold of `request` object here in the hook `def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):`
   The `item.config._xml` points to `LogXML` in `junit-xml` which in turn has no method `add_custom_property` associated with it.

So, 
What would be the best way to add more attributes to `junitxml`, so that it would roughly look like this -

```
<testcase classname="test_function" file="test_function.py" line="0" name="test_function" time="0.0009">
  <properties>
    <property name="jira" value="1234566" />
  </properties>
</testcase>
```

or like this

```
<testcase classname="test_function" file="test_function.py" line="0" name="test_function" time="0.0009" jira="2345667">
</testcase>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Looks like there is no easy way to achieve this. It is currently not supported by `pytest`. This is currently labelled as [feature request](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2827#issuecomment-336107573).